# How patching works in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am using BBB to understand the yocto-project. I am not sure how patching works. This is my project directory

```
├── meta-testlayer
├── poky
```

meta-test layer contains a "helloworld" example

```
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-hello
    └── helloworld
        ├── helloworld-0.1
        │   ├── helloworld.c
        │   ├── helloworld.patch
        │   └── newhelloworld.c
        └── helloworld_0.1.bb
```

"helloworld.c" and "newhelloworld.c" differ by only one `printf()` statement. Here is the content of "helloworld.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("Hi, this is my first custom recipe. Have a good day\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The content of "newhelloworld.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("Let see if patch works\n");
    printf("Hi, this patch is from the test-layer\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the patch I created using `diff helloworld.c newhelloworld.c > helloworld.patch` command.

```
6c6,7
<     printf("Hi, this is my first custom recipe. Have a good day\n");
---
>     printf("Let see if patch works\n");
>     printf("Hi, this patch is from the test-layer\n");
```

This is the content of "helloworld_0.1.bb" file

```
SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

#here we specify the source we want to build
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"
SRC_URI += "file://helloworld.patch"

#here we specify the source directory, where we can do all the building and expect sources to be placed
S = "${WORKDIR}"

#bitbake task
do_compile() {
         ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}

#bitbake task
do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

This is the error message when I run `bitbake -c patch helloworld`:

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: helloworld-0.1-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/guest/yocto_practice/poky/build-beaglebone/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/helloworld/0.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch helloworld.patch
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
Patch helloworld.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: helloworld-0.1-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/guest/yocto_practice/poky/build-beaglebone/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/helloworld/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_patch.22267
ERROR: Task (/home/guest/yocto_practice/meta-testlayer/recipes-hello/helloworld/helloworld_0.1.bb:do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 11 tasks of which 8 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/guest/yocto_practice/meta-testlayer/recipes-hello/helloworld/helloworld_0.1.bb:do_patch
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: There's not enough info here to tell why you were unable to apply the patch -- but maybe it conflicts with the other patch in meta-test? If you put your patch in meta-testlayer then you don't need a bbappend at all: you can just modify helloworld_0.1.bb.

Comment: shall I paste the log screenshot here ? Also how can to apply patch from same layer ?

Answer (score 26):

First, create the patch:

```
diff -u helloworld.c newhelloworld.c > helloworld.patch
```

or using Git (replace x by the number of commits you want to extract a patch):

```
git format-patch -x
```

Two ways to apply the patch:

- Put it into your test-layer, add a line on your .bb file:
  `SRC_URI += " file://example.patch "`
- Put it in another layer, but it's only needed if it isn't your layer (meta-oe, meta-fsl, meta-qt...)

For this case, use in your .bbappend file:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += " file://helloworld.patch "
```

Comment: I followed both the approaches, but may be I am doing something wrong within the patch file. As in the debug messages I can see the `only garbage was found inside the patch input`

Comment: Your patch is broken, how did you make it?

Comment: I have added my example.patch file content in the question.
If I do `bitabke helloworld` or `bitbake -c patch helloworld` I get errors.
One more thing I have to apply the patch first and then bake the recipe ?
Or can I directly bake the helloworld recipe.

Comment: `bitbake helloworld` runs the default "build" task which depends on "patch" task: in other words patching will happen automatically when needed

Comment: @jku but still I am unable to patch the recipe. I have example.patch and helloworld.c in same directory. And in helloworld_0.1.bb I added this line 
SRC_URI = "file://example.patch"

Comment: First, that's not the exact SRC_URI change @PierreOlivier suggested, second we can't help if you don't show your work: you need to post at least your bb file _and_ your patch file _and_ the exact error message you get.

Comment: Based on the screenshot of the error: your patch file is somehow broken (even if fixed it also wouldn't correctly patch the source code you pasted as far as I can tell -- it's just not a correct patch). Maybe you need to read up on how  patches work first?

Comment: Have edited the question, included all the files an patch with error message. Kindly have a look at the error now.

Comment: The diff command has to be invoked from one of the parent directory and this time I used `diff -u`. It worked. Thanks

Comment: If we have the changes in `git` already... why not just point to a new commit ID? Instead of managing individual patch files outside of `git`? Ironically, the patch files themselves will likely be in a git repo...

Answer (score 3):

Create a .bbappend file for that recipe.

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += " file://your.patch "
```

Answer (score 3):

- **bitbake -c devshell *recipe***
- **git init**
- **git add ***
- **git commit**   (sourcetree recorded by git)
- Edit the file in any editor you like and then save it  **eg.(vi */path/to/file*)**
- **git status** (shows that the file is modified)
- **git add */path/to/file***
- **git commit -m *"a sutaible comment according to the changes you made"***
- **git log** (shows that changes have be made and commit history)
- **git format-patch HEAD~1** (outputs the patch file created by the last commit)
- **ls** (check if patch file is there)
- Copy the patch file into **recipe/files** folder
- execute **exit** to exit devshell
- Edit **recipe.bb OR create recipe.bbappend** file and add patch file in **SRC_URI** variable
- Example:

```
   FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
   SRC_URI += " file://patchfile.patch "
```

- Build the image again with **bitbake *image_name***