# How to modify Yocto kernel (add,files and change files)

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I will appreciate it if someone can help with making some changes to the Yocto kernel for RSB-3430 (an Advantech SBC board).

Please check http://ess-wiki.advantech.com.tw/view/IoTGateway/BSP/Linux/iMX6/Yocto_LBV9_User_Guide#Getting_Started.

I am able to run docker container in order to build Yocto image "as is" after "repo init", "repo sync" and running bitbake (see below the main commands).
The next step is pushing some changes to the Yocto/poky kernel (to the security package of kernel).
I tried to add a patch which changes the security Makefile in order to add some files and compile them.
Unfortunately, it did not work.

In host machine:
docker pull advrisc/u16.04-imx8lbv1
docker run --privileged -it --name imx6LBV90107 -v ${HOME}/advantech/imx6LBV90107/adv-release-bsp:/home/adv/adv-release-bsp -v /dev:/dev advrisc/u16.04-imx8lbv1 /bin/bash

in docker container:
update git to git-2.32.0
update python3 to Python-3.6.15
udpate repo: curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
repo init -u git://github.com/ADVANTECH-Corp/adv-arm-yocto-bsp.git  -b imx-linux-sumo -m imx6LBV90017.xml
repo sync
MACHINE=imx6qrsb3430a1 DISTRO=fsl-imx-xwayland source fsl-setup-release.sh -b build_90017
bitbake fsl-image-validation-imx

My next steps should be:
create a patch for sources/meta-advantech/meta-fsl-imx8/recipes-kernel
patch should add files / folders to: tmp/work-shared/imx6qrsb3430a1/kernel-source/security/Makefile
run bitbake and create new image with modified kernel.

Comment: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Patching_the_source_for_a_recipe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584131/how-patching-works-in-yocto

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well, I'm trying to add a new module to the kernel.