yocto recipe, copy files to source code before compilation
I've been searching, googling, etc.   If I've found the answer I'm not sure, because I've not been using yocto/bitbake for very long.
I have a recipe for building u-boot for an embedded Linux system.   The u-boot is from a github I am sourcing with custom files added to it.  However, what I would prefer to do is pull u-boot from the official source  and then copy my files (stored in the recipe) to the source directory before it's compiled.
I am not sure which method to use to accomplish this.
do_install() seems to be for copying to the rootfs, not the working directory.

do_patch()  maybe ?

I think maybe do_configure() might work

how are you going to proceed with do_configure ? If you have mulitple files, juste add them manually, create a patch. In your recipe add your patch in do_patch. It will be easy. There are multiple solutions anyway

Something like this (untested)
    install -d ${S}/source_code_folder/
    cp ${WORKDIR}/file_to_copy.txt ${S}/source_code_folder/
    cp ${WORKDIR}/another_file.txt ${S}/source_code_folder/
    # Add more cp commands for additional files if needed
}```

(I don't know how to make that look right in a comment)

Yes you can it s fine

Does something prevent you from simply patching the source? That would be the cleanest and easiest to comprehend in a few years. See this question for how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584131/how-patching-works-in-yocto
